# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known what do i do

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error when I go to my website what does  mean?

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known

How can fix it so my website shows. I went from hostin from my house then to ma hosting service. idk where  I went wrong

Comment: are you using `file_get_contents` or `fsockopen` in your site?

Comment: i dont know how do i check

Answer (score 0):

just came across this and for research, the php application using the mysql pdo driver which was not installed (ubuntu -> php5-mysql).